# Regular expression to make sure that variable is constant

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to write a regular expression to make sure that variable is constant, given input like the following:

```
const size N = 1;
const size MAX = 1;
int const stant = 1147;
int x = 4;
```

Here is my expression that I've created:

```
const\s.*(\]|\s|\*)VARIABLETOCHECK(\(|\[|=|\s|;)
```

**Description of the expression:**

- `\s` - space afrer "const".
- `.*` - any number of any symbol.
- `(\]|\s|\*)` - symbols that should go before the variable.
- `VARIABLETOCHECK` is the place where I set my variable name that I want to check.
- `(\(|\[|=|\s|;)` - symbols that should go after the variable

**Problem:**

The problem is that if there is only a space after the word `const` my expression doesn't work.

And also each of the variables (`N`, `MAX`, `stant`) should match separately:

```
const\s.*(\]|\s|\*)N(\(|\[|=|\s|;)
```

This should select only the string: `const size N = 1;`

Comment: try making the expression match one space and optionally more. Additionally you should probably match for zero or more spaces around the equals sign because all of these are valid const declarations: `const size n = 1;`, `const-----size---n---=---1`, and `constsize n=1` (dashes indicate spaces)

Comment: There are many different variants of determining const variables.

Comment: Another one: const unsigned int width = 20, height = 20;";

Answer (score 1):

*Use regex:*

```
\bconst\b\s*(?:.*\b)?(VARIABLETOCHECK\b[^=]*?)\s*\=\s*(.*?)\s*[,;]
```

*See test code [here](http://ideone.com/Mn7sQ). If it validates "const" syntax, it returns the variable name and its value.*

Comment: "const unsigned int templ_width = 20, templ_height = 20;"; this is not processed correctly

Comment: @yurart - because it is not what you have posted in your question, where you have one assignment per line.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that. I'll fix it;

Comment: this is also matches:    void Output(const vector<pair<int,int> >& orderedQueries, const vector<map<int, int> >& queries)

Comment: and this variable must not be inside of brackets. Brackets could be on another line.

Comment: @yurart - you should not use regex for code parsing, there are so many possibilities that you cannot make it work with single regex - e.g. `x = "const int c = 3;";` is string, not code...

Comment: @yurart - for that particular case, fix would be `(?<!\()\s*\bconst\b\s*(?:.*\b)?(test\b[^=]*?)\s*\=\s*(.*?)\s*[,;]`

Comment: Ok then, what solution can you offer to solve my problem? I'd like to remind you. I have a file and I have a list of global variables that are in it. May task is to understand which are global.

Comment: I mean, may be some other more intelligent solutions exist?

Comment: @yurart - To better understand your problem and answer your question I would need to see the enitre code you are about to parse and the output you want to get. Otherwise it is just hip-hop fixing that goes nowhere...

Comment: please, tell me your e-mail or other way to send you the sources

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13170/discussion-between-yurart-and-mega)

Comment: @yurart - go to http://ideone.com/, choose C#, enter your test code there, click to "click here to enter input (stdin) or additional note" below the input window and insert your input there. Then click "submit", wait to process it and copy link from browser and post comment here with such link

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right your objective is to ensure an entry is a constant.

**Input:** Line of text

**Output expected:** True if its a constant, else False

---

**Regular expression:**

For this i suggest the following regex:

```
^.*?const\s+(\w+\s+)?(\w)\s+=.*$
```

Explanation:

`^` Start of line

`.*?` Any characters are matched and its non-greedy

`const` Keyword

`\s+` Atleast one whitespace

`(\w+\s+)?` Optional word which is not the name of variable.

`(\w)` Word which is the variable name.

`\s+` Optional whitespace

`=` Equals literal value

`.*` Any character

`$` End of line

Also the second group in the regular expression will get you your variable name, incase if you want to validate with predefined list of names.

---

**Outcome of above regex:**

`const size N = 1;` ==> **True**

`const size MAX = 1;` ==> **True**

`int const stant = 1147;`   ==> **True**

`int x = 4;`   ==> **False**

Optionally you can get the variable name by getting the second group in matcher.

**I would not hardcode VARIABLETOCHECK, and its a bad practice to hardcode in most cases.**

Answer (score 0):

This is very awkward, and only works for a few test cases in the language. Writing a regex that parses in the same way that c# does is very hard. But let's work with what you have.

you write "symbols that should go before the variable", but you mean "symbols that *could* go before the variable", right? So you need a `*` afterwards to say that those characters may or may not occur:

```
const\s.*(\]|\s|\*)*VARIABLETOCHECK(\(|\[|=|\s|;)
```

Now, you have `.*` before your variable, which means any string, really. You should probably exclude `;` and `=` at least, by using

```
const\s[^;=]*(\]|\s|\*)*VARIABLETOCHECK(\(|\[|=|\s|;)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong way.

The solution is the next:
1. download Doxygen
2. gen report in xml format
3. get global variables from xml

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expressions will identify all constants (integers, decimal...)

```
digit [0-9]
digits {digit}+
constant {digits}(.{digits})?((e|E)[+|-]?{digits})?
```

PS: This is for lex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow where answering questions is appreciated, but please read the question first. This question is about checking that C# declarations are of constants, it is not about simply detecting numbers. Hence this information about Lex is not useful.